# Google AdManager Order and Line items are stuck in 'Draft'

Tags: google-ad-manager

I'm attempting to set up some orders and line items in Google AdManager, formerly DFP. However whenever I create a new order and line item, they are stuck in 'Draft'. How do I approve them so they start delivering? I'm the account owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, Delivering > Orders > 'Select and Order to Edit' > Approve

The approve button is the first button on the left below the report row above 'Line Items' / ' Creatives'

Comment: Thanks. I spent close to an hour trying to figure out this UI